# openssl_public_encrypt and JSON

Tags: php, json

Let's say we need to store in a crypted way some confidential data into a db. And say that we need them into `json` format as will be more suitable for data reconstruction.

There's something that I miss that is driving me crazy.

Take that json for instance

```
$json = {"customer":{"customer_address":"Fake address 123","customer_city":"Fake City","customer_company":"","customer_countrycode":"it","customer_email":"","customer_telephone":"+39.347.xxxxxxx","customer_zip":"yyyyy"},"currency_code":"EUR","commision_amount":"84"}
```

now I want to crypt this `json` and I do the following

```
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($puk);
openssl_public_encrypt($json, $json_crypted, $pubKey);
```

if I `echo $json_crypted` it doesn't show anything, but if I remove some field (like `customer_company`, that is empty) all seems to work. I've tried to find something into documentation about this strange behaviour but I can't find anything.

Is someone aware of the reason behind that result?

### Edit

Even if I remove other field (not an empty one) all seems to work. I'm speechless because it has to be a silly thing that I can't understand

Comment: Check the result of openssl_public_encrypt. Does it return false when $json_crypted is empty?

Comment: @Getz: yes, of course. It fails, I perfectly know (and I've already verified it) but I would like to know ... why

Comment: @bouscher: no and if it was the case, encoding/decoding has nothing to do with json format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments in documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php#95307

> openssl_private_encrypt() has a low limit for the length of the data
>   it can encrypt due to the nature of the algorithm.
>
> To encrypt the larger data you can use openssl_encrypt() with a random
>   password (like sha1(microtime(true))), and encrypt the password with
>   openssl_public_encrypt(). This way the data can be encrypted with a
>   public key and decrypted with the private one.

Your json must exceed the length limit...

Comment: Yes, what a donk I am ... I haven't noticed that comment because I was sure that official documentation would have say a such important  thing

Comment: Indeed, the documentation should notify that.